# What is the best way to set <table> format?

Tags: html, css, html-table

**Demo Code:**

`<table>
    <tr>
        <tr>111</tr>
        <tr>222</tr>
        <tr>333</tr>
        <tr>444</tr>
        <tr>555</tr>
        <tr>666</tr>
    </tr>
</table>`

**I want output link this  without change in HTML use by the only CSS:**
111 222 333 
444 555 666

Can anyone  help me?

Comment: used to<tr> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>111</td>
<td>222</td>
<td>333</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>444</td>
<td>555</td>
<td>666</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I can't get a result as I mention above in output

Comment: what do you mean by above output, if you elaborate then I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Example HTML:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
    <th>Col5</th>
    <th>Col6</th>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>333</td>
        <td>444</td>
        <td>555</td>
        <td>666</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and for CSS:

```
th {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

th, tr {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: I know that but in my case, i cant change my HTML format,
any other way to set with the same HTML and per mention above using CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your real HTML code is:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>222</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>444</td>
    <td>555</td>
    <td>666</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

by using this CSS:

```css
td {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
  float: none;
}
```

you obtain what you want without changing the HTML

Comment: I can't get a result as I mention above in output

Comment: @yahil-madakiya I added a codepen sample here: http://codepen.io/kaosmos/pen/wWmaVp?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0):

```
tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
tr:nth-child(3) {
 float: none;
}
```

TR instead of TD (HTML change)

Comment: a TR inside another TR is wrong, so I assumed there is an error in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Demo Code:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>444</td>
  <td>555</td>
  <td>666</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```